# Wordpress wp_nonce как отключить проверочные ключи?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Здравствуйте, проблема в следующем:

Есть два движка WP работающих на разных базах но имеющие общие таблицы wp_users wp_usermeta,сделано чтобы иметь одну базу пользователей. На сайтах получается залогиниться нормально, но после того как на одном из сайтов выполнен выход на другом уже не войти.

Я думаю что проблема в wp_nonce, как то можно отключить проверочные ключи? только для входа выхода или полностью.

Comment: И сломать всю систему безопасности WordPress. Объедините ваши два сайта в мультисайт и не издевайтесь над WP.

Comment: Да я вынужден с вами согласиться, мультисайт хорошая штука. Может быть вы сталкивались со следуещей проблемой: использую ngnix перевел рабочий сайт, он с ssl, в режим мультисайта создал дочерний сайт на поддомене, теперь дочерний сайт доступен по https а по http недоступен. даже если делаю его alias-ом к основному серверу, не понимаю как такое вообще может быть

Comment: Настройки nginx разные для обычного сайта и мультисайта: https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx#WordPress_Multisite_subdomains_rules